# write content from a .css file to a text editor in python

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hello so in my python script im taking inputs from users and these inputs are written into parts of the css file.

```
    pag.moveTo(discord[0], discord[1], 0.5)
    pag.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    
    pag.moveTo(settings[0], settings[1], 0.5)
    pag.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    
    pag.moveTo(customcss[0], customcss[1], 0.5)
    pag.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    
    pag.moveTo(line1[0], line1[1], 0.5)
    pag.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    


    
    with open(name + '.css') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()


    pag.typewrite(lines)
```

The problem is when the code gets to `typewrite` the text in the `.css` file it just presses enter about 20 times and prints nothing from the file how can i fix this

Comment: Just do `lines = f.tead()`.  There's no reason to separate it into lines.

Answer (score 0):

The `pyautogui.typewrite()` function has two modes.  The first mode takes a `string` and simulates pressing a key for each of the letters in the string.  The second mode takes a `list` of strings, in which case it expects each string in the list to be a key name, not a character.

Here's documentation for the function:

> def typewrite(message, interval=0.0, logScreenshot=None, _pause=True):
>
> Performs a keyboard key press down, followed by a release, for each
> of the characters in message. The message argument can also be ***list of
> strings***, in which case ***any valid keyboard name*** can be used. Since this
> performs a sequence of keyboard presses and does not hold down keys,
> it cannot be used to perform keyboard shortcuts. Use the hotkey()
> function for that.
>
> Args:
>
> message (str, ***list***): If a string, then the
> characters to be pressed. ***If a
> list***, then ***the key names of the keys to press*** in order. The valid names
> are listed in KEYBOARD_KEYS.

Because you call `readlines()` to read your file, `lines` contains a list of strings, one for each line of the file.  If you instead called `read()`, `lines` would be a single string.  So with:

```
lines = f.readlines()
...
pag.typewrite(lines)
```

you are passing a list to `typewrite`. In that case, per the above documentation, the function expects each string in `lines` to contain ***key names, not characters.*** I assume that the file you're reading does not contain a list of key names.

If you use `f.read()` instead of `f.readlines()`, you'll get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Hey this is what i did at the end thanks.